# dateInput masking not working

Tags: kendo-ui, datetimepicker

DateInput is suppose to mask what the user is allowed to put into the input like:

```
<input id="test" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
        dateInput: true
    });
});
```

https://dojo.telerik.com/

This seems to work fine on the site, but if I use this in my project, the datetimepicker works fine, but it doesn't have a mask to start like in the dojo version and the user can put in whatever they want character wise. I don't see any errors, so does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you are using an older version in your project that does not include this feature.

Comment: Which version do I need?

Comment: Based on the release notes, the feature was first included in 2017.2.504